# Problemas con librería OpenVPN For Android [process-push-msg-failed]

Tags: android, vpn

Estoy recibiendo constantemente el error process-push-msg-failed al utilizar servidores de VPNGate, estos no están conectando y únicamente me están mostrando el error anterior.
Ya intenté cambiando el cipher a uno compatible con estos archivos de configuración pero siguen sin conectar, probé varias vpn de vpngate y todas continuan sin conectar en mi aplicación

Estoy construyendo una aplicación vpn a partir de cakevpn, código aquí: https://github.com/ashraf789/Cake-VPN

El archivo de configuración que estoy usando es este:

```
###############################################################################
# OpenVPN 2.0 Sample Configuration File
# for PacketiX VPN / SoftEther VPN Server
# 
# !!! AUTO-GENERATED BY SOFTETHER VPN SERVER MANAGEMENT TOOL !!!
# 
# !!! YOU HAVE TO REVIEW IT BEFORE USE AND MODIFY IT AS NECESSARY !!!
# 
# This configuration file is auto-generated. You might use this config file
# in order to connect to the PacketiX VPN / SoftEther VPN Server.
# However, before you try it, you should review the descriptions of the file
# to determine the necessity to modify to suitable for your real environment.
# If necessary, you have to modify a little adequately on the file.
# For example, the IP address or the hostname as a destination VPN Server
# should be confirmed.
# 
# Note that to use OpenVPN 2.0, you have to put the certification file of
# the destination VPN Server on the OpenVPN Client computer when you use this
# config file. Please refer the below descriptions carefully.


###############################################################################
# Specify the type of the layer of the VPN connection.
# 
# To connect to the VPN Server as a "Remote-Access VPN Client PC",
#  specify 'dev tun'. (Layer-3 IP Routing Mode)
#
# To connect to the VPN Server as a bridging equipment of "Site-to-Site VPN",
#  specify 'dev tap'. (Layer-2 Ethernet Bridgine Mode)

dev tun


###############################################################################
# Specify the underlying protocol beyond the Internet.
# Note that this setting must be correspond with the listening setting on
# the VPN Server.
# 
# Specify either 'proto tcp' or 'proto udp'.

proto tcp


###############################################################################
# The destination hostname / IP address, and port number of
# the target VPN Server.
# 
# You have to specify as 'remote <HOSTNAME> <PORT>'. You can also
# specify the IP address instead of the hostname.
# 
# Note that the auto-generated below hostname are a "auto-detected
# IP address" of the VPN Server. You have to confirm the correctness
# beforehand.
# 
# When you want to connect to the VPN Server by using TCP protocol,
# the port number of the destination TCP port should be same as one of
# the available TCP listeners on the VPN Server.
# 
# When you use UDP protocol, the port number must same as the configuration
# setting of "OpenVPN Server Compatible Function" on the VPN Server.

remote public-vpn-133.opengw.net 443


###############################################################################
# The HTTP/HTTPS proxy setting.
# 
# Only if you have to use the Internet via a proxy, uncomment the below
# two lines and specify the proxy address and the port number.
# In the case of using proxy-authentication, refer the OpenVPN manual.

;http-proxy-retry
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port]


###############################################################################
# The encryption and authentication algorithm.
# 
# Default setting is good. Modify it as you prefer.
# When you specify an unsupported algorithm, the error will occur.
# 
# The supported algorithms are as follows:
#  cipher: [NULL-CIPHER] NULL AES-128-CBC AES-192-CBC AES-256-CBC BF-CBC
#          CAST-CBC CAST5-CBC DES-CBC DES-EDE-CBC DES-EDE3-CBC DESX-CBC
#          RC2-40-CBC RC2-64-CBC RC2-CBC
#  auth:   SHA SHA1 MD5 MD4 RMD160

cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1


###############################################################################
# Other parameters necessary to connect to the VPN Server.
# 
# It is not recommended to modify it unless you have a particular need.

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
#auth-user-pass


###############################################################################
# The certificate file of the destination VPN Server.
# 
# The CA certificate file is embedded in the inline format.
# You can replace this CA contents if necessary.
# Please note that if the server certificate is not a self-signed, you have to
# specify the signer's root certificate (CA) here.

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
TzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxKTAnBgNVBAoTIEludGVybmV0IFNlY3VyaXR5IFJlc2Vh
cmNoIEdyb3VwMRUwEwYDVQQDEwxJU1JHIFJvb3QgWDEwHhcNMTUwNjA0MTEwNDM4
WhcNMzUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WjBPMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJu
ZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2ggR3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMTDElTUkcgUm9vdCBY
MTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK3oJHP0FDfzm54rVygc
h77ct984kIxuPOZXoHj3dcKi/vVqbvYATyjb3miGbESTtrFj/RQSa78f0uoxmyF+
0TM8ukj13Xnfs7j/EvEhmkvBioZxaUpmZmyPfjxwv60pIgbz5MDmgK7iS4+3mX6U
A5/TR5d8mUgjU+g4rk8Kb4Mu0UlXjIB0ttov0DiNewNwIRt18jA8+o+u3dpjq+sW
T8KOEUt+zwvo/7V3LvSye0rgTBIlDHCNAymg4VMk7BPZ7hm/ELNKjD+Jo2FR3qyH
B5T0Y3HsLuJvW5iB4YlcNHlsdu87kGJ55tukmi8mxdAQ4Q7e2RCOFvu396j3x+UC
B5iPNgiV5+I3lg02dZ77DnKxHZu8A/lJBdiB3QW0KtZB6awBdpUKD9jf1b0SHzUv
KBds0pjBqAlkd25HN7rOrFleaJ1/ctaJxQZBKT5ZPt0m9STJEadao0xAH0ahmbWn
OlFuhjuefXKnEgV4We0+UXgVCwOPjdAvBbI+e0ocS3MFEvzG6uBQE3xDk3SzynTn
jh8BCNAw1FtxNrQHusEwMFxIt4I7mKZ9YIqioymCzLq9gwQbooMDQaHWBfEbwrbw
qHyGO0aoSCqI3Haadr8faqU9GY/rOPNk3sgrDQoo//fb4hVC1CLQJ13hef4Y53CI
rU7m2Ys6xt0nUW7/vGT1M0NPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNV
HRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBR5tFnme7bl5AFzgAiIyBpY9umbbjANBgkq
hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAVR9YqbyyqFDQDLHYGmkgJykIrGF1XIpu+ILlaS/V9lZL
ubhzEFnTIZd+50xx+7LSYK05qAvqFyFWhfFQDlnrzuBZ6brJFe+GnY+EgPbk6ZGQ
3BebYhtF8GaV0nxvwuo77x/Py9auJ/GpsMiu/X1+mvoiBOv/2X/qkSsisRcOj/KK
NFtY2PwByVS5uCbMiogziUwthDyC3+6WVwW6LLv3xLfHTjuCvjHIInNzktHCgKQ5
ORAzI4JMPJ+GslWYHb4phowim57iaztXOoJwTdwJx4nLCgdNbOhdjsnvzqvHu7Ur
TkXWStAmzOVyyghqpZXjFaH3pO3JLF+l+/+sKAIuvtd7u+Nxe5AW0wdeRlN8NwdC
jNPElpzVmbUq4JUagEiuTDkHzsxHpFKVK7q4+63SM1N95R1NbdWhscdCb+ZAJzVc
oyi3B43njTOQ5yOf+1CceWxG1bQVs5ZufpsMljq4Ui0/1lvh+wjChP4kqKOJ2qxq
4RgqsahDYVvTH9w7jXbyLeiNdd8XM2w9U/t7y0Ff/9yi0GE44Za4rF2LN9d11TPA
mRGunUHBcnWEvgJBQl9nJEiU0Zsnvgc/ubhPgXRR4Xq37Z0j4r7g1SgEEzwxA57d
emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</ca>


###############################################################################
# The client certificate file (dummy).
# 
# In some implementations of OpenVPN Client software
# (for example: OpenVPN Client for iOS),
# a pair of client certificate and private key must be included on the
# configuration file due to the limitation of the client.
# So this sample configuration file has a dummy pair of client certificate
# and private key as follows.

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

</key>
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Qué tengo que tocar en el archivo de configuración para que funcione?